# I can't import or install qrcode in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I can't get this to work and I've tried a lot. I keep getting this error. I tried to reinstall python3 and vs code.

If I could get any help I'd feel really thankful to you! Is there anything I'm missing?

https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/ehavuxafin.lua < the error.`

I got it to work but now I'm getting this error.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtfwr.png)

Comment: can you please give a list of what you've tried?

Comment: I've tried installing all the requirements one by one..

see here
https://pastebin.com/aLVPDEHH

The code I am using is here...

https://pastebin.com/110UPepC

here's a screenshot

https://i.imgur.com/kAuMxfY.png

here's the error the yellow text is showing...

https://i.imgur.com/J0Kyh1U.png

here is the view problem...
https://i.imgur.com/ABKmept.png